# Why git branch -r shows two names for same branch: origin/master AND [repo name]/master?

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Noting that i've executed:

```
git fetch
```

and

```
git fetch --prune
```

Same result.

My output of `git branch -r`:
[image: I get both origin/master and daal-backend/master]

I got confused in the beginning thinking i had created duplicate branches, but in the repo page, there's only one master. (Even 'dev-daal' is deleted)

**EDIT 1:**

I tried doing

```
git fetch --all
```

and now I have two versions of everything:
[image: after git fetch --all]

Comment: You've got two remotes. Say `git remote -v` to see a list.  If they are two names for the same thing, you can delete one.

Comment: @matt Ah, so I mistakenly added same tracked repos with different names? and now git fetches them both each time?

Comment: Only if you say `--all`. Most of the time it just ignores the first one.

Comment: By the way, no pictures of code, please! That was text; you can just copy and paste it right into the question (and format it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `git branch -r` command lists your *remote-tracking names*.  Git calls them "remote-tracking branch names" in some of its documentation, but despite Git's extreme overuse of the word "branch", remote-tracking names are not *branch* names in one very important sense.  That's why I like to leave out the misleading word and just call them "remote-tracking names".

In any case, there are several things to know about remote-tracking names:

1. They're in *your* repository.  They don't necessarily mean anything about any other repository, except for the next point.
2. Your Git software *creates or updates* them, in your repository, when your Git software connects to other Git software that is working with some other Git repository, and that other Git software tells your Git software that the *other* repository currently has some branch names.  Since branch names are temporary and meaningless, but useful for locating *commits* (which are permanent and meaningful), your Git software *copies* those names to your repository, so that you can use their names.  But since those are *their* branch names, not yours, your Git *renames* their branch names.
3. The name you get—the remote-tracking name—is made by taking the name you use to *talk to* their Git software, such as `origin` or `Daal-Backend`, adding one slash `/`, and then using their *branch* name.  So if your Git software is using the name `Daal-Backend` to talk to some other Git software, and that other Git software tells you that, at this very instant, *they* have a branch named `master`, *your* Git will create or update the name `Daal-Backend/master` in *your* repository so that you can easily retrieve the hash ID of the commit that *they* are currently calling `master`.

If they—whoever they are—rename their `master`, your Git will pick up the new name the next time your Git calls up their Git and converses with them about their branch names.  At that time, your Git software will create a new name, `Daal-Backend/main` for instance, based on their new name.  Your Git *won't* **delete** your old name unless you tell it to.

Likewise, if they *delete* their `master` entirely (which they could do if they wanted: there's nothing special about the name `master`) and your Git calls up their Git, your Git won't do anything, because your Git is not seeing their `master` any more.  You must tell your Git *if you talk to them and they don't have that branch name at all, delete my copy*.  You would do this with `git fetch --prune Daal-Backend`.  That has your Git ask their Git about all their branch names, creating or updating your remote-tracking names as appropriate and also *deleting* any *stale, left-over* names.

Note that this all assumes that you're having your Git software use the name `Daal-Backend` to call up their Git software.  Should you now use the name `origin`—as in `git fetch origin`—to call up any other Git software, whether it's theirs or not, and get information about *another* repository, this time your Git software will create and/or update your `origin/*` names.

So it's all up to the name you use to contact what Git calls a *remote*.  A *remote* is just a short name for some other Git repository: the remote hangs on to the URL.  You will use `git remote add` to *add* a remote, or `git remote remove` to *remove* a remote.  The existence of that remote, plus you running `git fetch`, plus the existence of the branch names *on* that remote, is what causes you to have remote-tracking names.

Comment: Got at! Thanks a lot for the overview. Apparently, while doing `git init`, I added same remote repo twice. Once without naming it, and it got the `origin` by default, then another time to name it as `Daal-backend`, thinking it will rename only.

Answer (score 1):

You've got two remotes. Say `git remote -v` to see a list.  If they are two names for the same URL, you can remove one.

```
git remote rm Daal-Backend
```

Comment: Got it!
They are referencing same link, except, one with `.git` at the end, and one without.
Does that make any difference?

Comment: No, no difference.